# AWS - Sharepoint vs inhouse AD Server authentication

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, sharepoint-2010

I have an inhouse setup at our office with Sharepoint 2010 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2, a MS SQL Server 2008 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 and a AD Server. I am planning to migrate Sharepoint 2010 and DB Server alone to AWS. I would like to retain my AD server inhouse itself. Now how do I authenticate AD users to Sharepoint Sever. Please consider me as an Windows Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Either have site to site Virtual Private Network (VPN) between AWS and your facility, so  all servers look like they are on same network.

Or setup Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) servers on both ends to exchange claims over the internet.